# How to get tab pane content to scroll using Bootstrap and scrollToFixed jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

We're using jQuery Mobile, Bootstrap 3, scrollToFixed. We've put together a working page that does almost what we need, however, we can't get the tab content to scroll up.

We've included the HTML here:

```
<div class="container">
<img src="" width="100%" height="50" alt="logo" style="height:50px;display:block;" />
<nav id="menuone" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"> 
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#or_mainnav">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button> 
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="or_mainnav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">item one</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">drop two <b class="caret"></b></a> 
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">subitem one</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">subitem two</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">item three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item four</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<img src="" width="100%" height="200" alt="product picture" style="height:200px;display:block;" /> 

<div class="headertwo">
    <h2>
        Product Title
    </h2>
</div>

<div id="menutwo">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#product_main" data-toggle="tab">item one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#product_two" data-toggle="tab">item two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#product_threes" data-toggle="tab">item three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#product_four" data-toggle="tab">item four</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="tabcontent" class="content tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="product_main">
        <div>
            Main
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="product_two">
        Two
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="product_threes">
        Three
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="product_four">
        Four
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://raw.githack.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed/master/jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js"></script>
```

Our Javascript is this:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() { 
  var menuOneHeight = $('#menuone').outerHeight(); 
  var menuTwoHeight = $('#menutwo').outerHeight();
  var headerOneHeight = $('.headertwo').outerHeight();
  $('#menuone').scrollToFixed();
  $('.headertwo').scrollToFixed({
    marginTop: menuOneHeight
  });
  $('#menutwo').scrollToFixed({
    marginTop: menuOneHeight+headerOneHeight
  });
  $('#tabcontent').scrollToFixed({
    marginTop: menuOneHeight+headerOneHeight+menuTwoHeight
  });
  $('#product_main').load('/jemef/2');
});

</script>
```

We've created a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/outofcontrol/LSEZp/

With the first tab "tab one" active, scroll down, you can see the tab-pane content is hidden below the bottom of the page. We'd like the content in the tab-pane to scroll up. Does anyone know how we might accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work, I removed the scrollToFixed() entry in JS for #tabcontent. A working sample of this page can be found on JSFiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var menuOneHeight = $('#menuone').outerHeight(); 
var menuTwoHeight = $('#menutwo').outerHeight();
var headerOneHeight = $('.headertwo').outerHeight();

  $('#menuone').scrollToFixed();
  $('.headertwo').scrollToFixed({
    marginTop: menuOneHeight
  });
  $('#menutwo').scrollToFixed({
    marginTop: menuOneHeight+headerOneHeight
  });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/outofcontrol/LSEZp/1/